# fft with non uneven spacing between the value of the signal

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to implement in C or C++ a solution for a fft and Ifft when the signal values are not obtained at a constant rate, making it having a desviation between the values and the periodic ones. I do not know how I can change the algorithm of calculating the fft with synchronized signals as in https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/02a7699d274d226871209491c8a05976d6e46cf3 into a uneven spacing values of signal.

One of my ideas is using the values to make the completed signal and then catchiing the correct points, but it is a very time consuming solution, and i think that as we have a deviation

The overall objective is to have the fft as described and the ifft values in that points

Comment: You probably want to look at non-uniform FFTs. If I'm not mistaken, the premise is essentially interpolation to uniformly-spaced points and use standard FFT. See: http://www.cims.nyu.edu/cmcl/nufft/nufft.html

Answer (score 1):

Like @Steve already said in a comment, the correct answer is to look for "nonuniform fast Fourier transform" algorithms. There is both a significant literature, as well as open source software packages on this topic.